# Bash script to increase date range per month

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I want increase date range of my worker node eg

```
`startdate="2020-01-01T15:04:05Z"`
`endDate="2020-02-01T15:04:05Z`

runWorker(startDate, endDate) {
   // once worker is done

   // increment startDate to 
   `startDate="2020-02-01T15:04:05Z`
   `endDate="2020-03-01T15:04:05Z`
}
```

How can I get create a bash script to do this thank you.

I want to create a date range which would be used by a worker that is extracting logs and saving to a storage and after the extraction is done, I want to increase the range by a month so the new data range would be used to run the worker.

in essense what I am trying to achieve

- startDate=2020-01-01T15:04:05Z
- endDate=2020-02-01T15:04:05Z
- run worker
- worker completes for the time stipulated
- Increase the range to cover another month range
- run worker for the new range.

Comment: something like `date --date='$currentValue next month' +%FT%T%Z` maybe? E.g. `date --date='2020-02-01T15:04:05Z next month' +%FT%T%Z` adds a month to given date

Comment: I do not fully understand your comment @MikhailAntonov. You could use the Answers pane.

Comment: well I didn't understand the question fully too, to be honest. Do you want to replace the given date within one script file by running another script? Or you just want to update the variable which contains the date? If the latter, calling `date` program with arguments that I suggested, should do the trick. If you want the first thing, this should be fed to `sed` with some more magic

Comment: Check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU coretutils's `date`:

```
$ date --utc -d $startdate"+1 month" "+%FT%TZ"
2020-02-01T15:04:05Z
```

If you used ISO time zones, you'd:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d $start"+1 month" "+%FT%T%Z"
2020-02-01T15:04:05UTC
```

Notice the difference `Z` and `%Z`.

Comment: I got `date: illegal option -- -`

Comment: I am Using a Mac OS.

Comment: `sh lokilogs.sh`
`usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: And if you remove the `--utc` and try to deal with it using `TZ=GMT`? I don't have access to a Mac here.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I could come up with under OSX is:

```
#!/bin/bash
startDate="2020-01-01T15:04:05Z"
endDate="2020-02-01T15:04:05Z"

function runWorker() {
    echo "Processing $startDate - $endDate"
    echo "worker does it's stuff here"

    # increment date range
    startDate=$(TZ=UTC date -j -v+1m -f "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ" "$startDate" +%FT%TZ)
    endDate=$(TZ=UTC date -j -v+1m -f "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ" "$endDate" +%FT%TZ)
}

# Repeat a bunch of times to skip one year
for i in `seq 0 14`; do
    runWorker
done
```

It seems to have the behavior you're after. You should reference `man date` page as I'm not really confident about my format string. The following part is really important:

> Adjusting the date by months is inherently ambiguous because a month
> is a unit of variable length depending on the current date.  This kind
> of date
> adjustment is applied in the most intuitive way.  First of all, date tries to preserve the day of the month.  If it is
> impossible because the target
> month is shorter than the present one, the last day of the target month will be the result.  For example, using -v +1m on May
> 31 will adjust the date
> to June 30, while using the same option on January 30 will result in the date adjusted to the last day of February.  This
> approach is also believed
> to make the most sense for shell scripting.  Nevertheless, be aware that going forth and back by the same number of
> months may take you to a differ-
> ent date.

I also didn't bother about the time zones in hope that you'll figure it out by yourself.

PS: I also believe it is better to calculate `endDate` by adding a month to `startDate`, but that also takes some effort to be done properly so that there would be no skipped date ranges and such.